# Angular PrimeNG DataTable Show a nested JSON as a custom string in one column

Tags: arrays, angular, datatable, primeng

I have this array:

```
const users: any[] = [{
    name: 'name',
    surname: 'surname',
    username: 'username',
    email: 'email@email.com',
    tel: '72837129',
    role: {
        role1: 'role1',
        role2: 'role2',
        role3: 'role3'
    },
    address: '',
    cell: '',
    fax: ''
}, {
    name: 'name2',
    surname: 'surname2',
    username: 'username2',
    email: 'email@email.com',
    tel: '72837129',
    role: {
        role1: 'role1',
        role2: 'role2',
        role3: 'role3'
    },
    address: '',
    cell: '',
    fax: ''
}];
```

I want to display nested JSON attribute role as as one string like that `role1, role2, role3` in a single column called Role in the PrimeNG DataTable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show your ui page how you want to display ?

Answer (score 0):

you can traverse your users array and overwrite `role` as:

```
users = users.map(user => {
    user.role = [];
    for (let key in obj) {
      user.role.push(obj[key]);
    }
    user.role = user.role.toString();
    return user;
});
```